# cytoscapejs - embed html inside node body

Tags: javascript, html, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

This might be a stupid question but is it possible to put html inside a cytoscape js node? I've been through the docs and it suggests that it's possible to put an image inside a node, but says nothing about html. Ideally this is so I can have a set of images along with tool tips which float above the images.
Thanks in advance.
Joe

Comment: _"What do you have so far?"_

Answer (score 4):

You can't mix HTML content with canvas, which is the underlying rendering technology Cytoscape.js uses.  You can use SVG images, and SVGs are very similar to the HTML DOM and can be manipulated with JS libraries -- though layout is mostly manual in SVG.

Options:

(1) Use SVG.  You can just grab the SVG content, URL encode it (with `encodeURI()`), and use that as the background image, e.g.:

`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10px" height="7px"><g><g><polygon points="8.433,-0.06 4.985,3.325 1.539,-0.06 -0.066,1.546 4.985,6.566 10.037,1.546" fill="%2361B23B"/></g></g></svg>`

You'll need the `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,` prefix as in the example.

(2) Build an [extension](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions) that puts a div on top of each node.  You'll have to do some organising in the extension to sync the div positions with the nodes etc.